# Get HDFS files based on timestamp in java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have to filter a list of files from hdfs folder based on their timestamp using java.

Example:

```
File    TimeStamp

File1   22nd January 2015
File2   21st January 2015
File3   20th January 2015
```

Considering above example, I have to get a list of files which were created between `20th January 2015` and `21st January 2015`.
Which will be:

```
File2
File3
```

How can I do this in java?

Comment: what have you done ?

Comment: Use the File.lastModified() method.

Answer (score 1):

Use [listStatus](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path[],%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathFilter)) with a [PathFilter](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/PathFilter.html) instance that filters based on the getModificationTime method of [FileStatus](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html#getModificationTime()).

Comment: can you give sample code ? This information is useful for me but i am bit confuse that how do use it my actual code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a code similar to this to get file creation time in the form of a string or covert into another object if you wish (You need to get HDFS path object if you want to perform the operations on HDFS files)

```
    Path file = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".", "filename");
    BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);

    System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());

    FileTime creationDate = attr.creationTime();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String dateCreated = df.format(creationDate.toMillis());
    System.out.println(dateCreated);
```

Take a look at these java docs and tutorials for more information [Managing Metadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html), [BasicFileAttributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html) and [FileTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html).